# Can it take a long time for `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` to be reached after calling `startUpdatingLocation`?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Until now, my experience has been that `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` is called almost immediately after I have called `startUpdatingLocation`.

However, I need to know: Can I rely on this always being so quick, i.e. almost instantaneous? Are there scenarios in which this might take a long time? If so, what are those scenarios?

(Of course, in some cases the `locationManager:didFailWithError:` method is called instead. So one could also ask whether or not, if this method is called, one can rely on it being called almost instantaneously.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have perfectly strong GPS signal, or no signal at all, CoreLocation may decide to try to determine your location by using a Wi-Fi or mobile Internet network. In this case, this task may take a while.

Answer (score 0):

No you should not rely on the first few updates..location manager gradually settles to an accurate location not before it shows some random inaccurate location..

i do this code to filter location updates

```
   NSTimeInterval secondsSinceLastPoint = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
    if(secondsSinceLastPoint < 2)
    {
        return NO; //Not valid.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not depend on timing behavior that is not in the spec for the API.

Furthermore, the first location updates you get could be way way off if the GPS circuitry or other radios are just waking up from a powered-down state.